# Differences between Jenkins docker-agent and docker-inbound-agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I couldn't get the differences or better say the benefits of using **docker-agent** or **docker-inbound-agent** for Jenkins as part of Cloud Nodes.

currently, I am using the routine Docker configuration for **Configuration Cloud** to use docker as agent to build application.

- Jenkins Controller running on Host#1
- another host for running docker agents!

based on GitHub readme:

> docker-inbound-agent is using TCP or WebSockets to establish inbound connection to the Jenkins master.

- [docker-agent](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-agent)
- [docker-inbound-agent](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-inbound-agent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [docker-agent](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-agent) readme on github :

> This image is used as the basis for the Docker Inbound Agent image. In
> that image, the container is launched externally and attaches to
> Jenkins.
>
> This image may instead be used to launch an agent using the **Launch
> method** of **Launch agent via execution of command on the master**.

[docker-agent](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-agent) is used to launch an agent with a command on the master :

[image: launch method master]

This launch the agent on the master.

[docker-inbound-agent](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-inbound-agent) got the docker-agent image as basis (see on a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-inbound-agent/blob/master/11/alpine/Dockerfile)) :

```
ARG version=latest-alpine-jdk11
FROM jenkins/agent:$version
```

This image was before named `jnlp-slave` (see this [link](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/05/06/docker-agent-image-renaming/)) which got the same goal. This setup an agent which connect to the jenkins using the TCP protocol.

You also have a third agent, the [docker-ssh-agent](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-ssh-agent) which is used to be connected to the master with SSH.